# notifyDataSetChanged not working until pressing edittext

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerlistview

I am new to Android, I apologize if I have done things the wrong way. Your suggestions are welcomed.
I tried to connect SOAP webserice with my Android and show the received data to the recyclerView. I have an editText to type a key for sending requests to SOAP. Send request and receive data steps are worked well, however, when I tried to show the data to the recyclerView by using **notifyDataSetChanged()**, the recycler view was not updated until I touch editText again.

Here I Send Request and receive data, I also try to update adapter by notifyDataSetChanged:

```
btnInvoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain(connectSOAP.getHandler(),new SOAPCONNECT());
                msg.what = SOAPCONNECT;
                msg.sendToTarget();
            }
        });

//here is the SOAP implementation
private class SOAPCONNECT implements Runnable{
        String str;
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/DanhSachSanPham";
        private String METHOD_NAME = "DanhSachSanPham";
        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String URL = "https://www.minhyeuphuong.com/TestSOAP.asmx?WSDL";
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("maGoiHang",edtMaGoiHang.getText().toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                ht.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                str = envelope.bodyIn.toString();
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                if(str!=null){
                    SoapObject Sanpham = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
                    int tongSP = Sanpham.getPropertyCount();
                    for (int i = 0;i<tongSP;i++){
                        SoapObject Sanpham1 = (SoapObject) Sanpham.getProperty(i);
                        arrSanPham.add(new 
                        SanPham(Integer.parseInt(Sanpham1.getProperty("MaSanPham").toString()),
                                Integer.parseInt(Sanpham1.getProperty("SoLuong").toString()),
                                Sanpham1.getProperty("TenSanPham").toString()));
                    }

                }else
                    Log.d("WebRespone", "ERROR");
                listSPAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Error","Error while recieving data");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my Adapter initialization and adapter class.

```
//adapter initialization
        arrSanPham          = new ArrayList<SanPham>();
        listSPAdapter       = new ListSPAdapter(arrSanPham);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rcvSanPham.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rcvSanPham.setAdapter(listSPAdapter);
//adapter class
public class ListSPAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
   /*Khoi tao adapter de control thanh phan cua recycle view*/
    private ArrayList<SanPham> arrSanPham;

    public ListSPAdapter(ArrayList<SanPham> arrSanPham) {
        this.arrSanPham = arrSanPham;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listsanpham,parent,false);
        return new ListSanPhamHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListSanPhamHolder viewHolder = (ListSanPhamHolder) holder;
        viewHolder.txtTenSP.setText(arrSanPham.get(position).getTenSanPham());
        viewHolder.txtMaSP.setText(""+arrSanPham.get(position).getMaSanPham());
        viewHolder.txtSoLuong.setText(""+arrSanPham.get(position).getSoLuong());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrSanPham.size();
    }

    /*Holder để hold cac thanh phan cua layout*/
    public static class ListSanPhamHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtMaSP,txtTenSP,txtSoLuong;
        public ListSanPhamHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtMaSP         = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMaSP_listsanpham);
            txtTenSP        = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTenSP_listsanpham);
            txtSoLuong      = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSoLuong_listsanpham);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your adapter initialization and adapter class.

Comment: i added my adapter class